# Custom Toolbar in navigation control in ios doesnot show button text (add button + and edit button text in this case)

Tags: ios, iphone

```
//Adding Right Bar Add Button
UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertData)];
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=addBarButton;
```

```
 UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0,20, 150, 30)];
 toolBar.barStyle= style
 toolBar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 toolBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:addBarButton,self.editButtonItem,nil];
 [toolBar setItems:items];
 UIBarButtonItem *barItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barItem;
 self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bug in your code.

Either remove this line or give it some other color.

```
toolBar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

or change it to

```
toolBar.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

That solves your problem.

Comment: Thanku very much ..it works .

Comment: Looks like You forgot to up-vote. Thanks. :-)

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation sir ..nd i just started sry for this